# How to stop a looping animation with componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a page that contains different components, one of these components have a looping animation in it, I will start the animation when the child component mounted. I want to stop the animation when I change to another screen. so I tried to stop animation in containing a component in the componentWillUnmount lifecycle, it runs my stop function but after that, it will keep running animation again and I don't know how to stop it.

Actually, I want to keep my memory safe, I want to animation starts only when this component mount and stop when unmounted.

this is my first component which contains my animating child component(StoreBoxItems)  :

```
export class StoreBoxPackages extends Component {
  render() {
    const {    
      onPress,
      packTitle,
      currency,      
      discount,      
      items,
      price,
      packageType,
      keyIndex,
      packID,      
    } = this.props;
    //let b = [];
    let rows = []
    let itemsNumber = 0; 
    if (items != null){
      //console.log('ssssxxxx')
      itemsNumber = items.length; 
    }
    //console.log('itemsNumber', itemsNumber)   
    let rowsNumber = Math.ceil(itemsNumber/3);
    //console.log('rowNum' , rowsNumber)
    let boxIndex = 0;
    for(let i = 1; i <= rowsNumber; i++){
      let row = [];
      for(let j = 0; j< 3 && boxIndex<itemsNumber; j++,boxIndex++){               
          row.push(
            <StoreBoxItems
              stateKey={`${i}${j}`}
              price={price}
              currency={currency} 
              unit={items[boxIndex].unit}
              type={items[boxIndex].type}
              titleColor={items[boxIndex].caption_color}
              duration={items[boxIndex].duration}
              ientifier={items[boxIndex].identifier}
              asset_id={items[boxIndex].asset_id}
              packageType={packageType}
              caption={items[boxIndex].caption}
              itemID={packID}
              onPress={onPress}
            />
          )
          if(boxIndex + 1 == itemsNumber && itemsNumber > 3){
              let reminder = itemsNumber % 3;              
              let moreBox = 3 - reminder;
              //console.log('boxIndex', boxIndex ,'itemsNumber', itemsNumber, 'reminder', reminder , 'moreBox', moreBox)
              if(reminder != 0 && moreBox > 0){
                 for(let k=0;k<moreBox;k++){
                   row.push(<View style={{flex : 1}}></View>) 
                 } 
              }
          }               
      }
      rows.push(
        <View key={makeid(8)} style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
            {row}          
        </View>
      )
    }    
      return (
        <View key={makeid(8)} style={{flexGrow: 1}}>          
            {rows} 
          <View>
            {packageType == 'COLLECTION' ?
            <StoreBoxItemsBtn
              price={price}
              currency={currency}
              itemID={packID}
              onPress={onPress}
            />
            : null }
          </View>
        </View>                  
      );    
  }
}
```

and here is my child animating component (StoreBoxItems)

```
export class StoreBoxItems extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: new Animated.Value(0),
      appState: AppState.currentState
    };
    this.backColor = '#201F3F';
    this.runAnimationSate = true;
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    //this._chackBackColor()
    this.runAnimation();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange); 
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
    console.log('unmonted anime');
    this.runAnimationSate = false;
    Animated.timing(this.state.progress).stop();
    //Animated.loop(Animated.timing(this.state.progress)).stop();  
  }

  runAnimation() {
    console.log('run animation');
    this.state.progress.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 3000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver : true
    })
    .start(() => {
        if (this.runAnimationSate) {
            this.runAnimation();
        }
    })
}

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active"){
      console.log('active')
      this.runAnimation();
    }else{
      console.log('DEactive')      
        Animated.timing(this.state.progress).stop();
        this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }
}

  render() {
    const {
      stateKey,    
      price,
      currency,
      caption,
      unit,
      type,
      duration,
      ientifier,
      asset_id,
      titleColor,
      packageType,
      itemID,
      onPress
    } = this.props; 
    let itemHeader = '';
    let xduration = 0;
    switch (type) {
      case "BOOSTER" :
      xduration =  (duration / 3600);
      if(xduration >= 1){
        itemHeader = `${xduration} H, ${ientifier}x`;
      }else{
        xduration =  (duration / 60);
        itemHeader = `${xduration} Min, ${ientifier}x`;
      }

      break;
      case "COIN" :
      itemHeader = unit;
      break;
      default :
      itemHeader = unit;
      break;
   }
      return (
        <View key={makeid(8)} style={[styles.boxItems]}>
          <View style={[styles.boxItemIconHolder,{backgroundColor : this.backColor}]}>
            <Text style={[{color : titleColor}, globalStyles.mediumFont, globalStyles.acmeFont]}>{itemHeader}</Text>
            <Image
              source={icons[asset_id]}
              style={{ width: normalize(40), height: normalize(40), marginTop: 2 }}
            />
            {type == "COIN" ?
            <LottieView
              style={{               
                position: 'absolute',
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                zIndex:1
              }}
                progress={this.state.progress}              
                source={lotties['shineBox']}
                loop={true}                            
                //autoPlay={true}
            />
            : null }
          </View>
          <Text style={[globalStyles.lightColor, globalStyles.mediumFont, globalStyles.acmeFont, styles.boxItemTitle]}>{caption}</Text>
          {packageType == 'ITEM' ?
          <StoreBoxItemsBtn
            price={price}
            currency={currency} 
            itemID={itemID}
            onPress={onPress}
          />
          : null }
        </View>           
      );    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's weird because it seems that you are doing it correctly, have you tried this.state.progress.stopAnimation() ?

Additionally, my advice is to [do not put animated value into state](https://codeburst.io/butter-smooth-animations-in-react-native-93a3b86adf1)

> State values are used in React and React Native to dynamically update
>   a component. This means that the render() method of the component is
>   called every time the state is updated.
>
> Now you might think that since since the component is updated
>   dynamically, it would be okay to store animated values in state.
>
> Suppose we have mapped an animated scroll event onto the state. So on
>   every scroll, the render method will be called, leading to an
>   unnecessary overhead. So if we scroll 700px on the screen, the render
>   method is updated 700 times.

Answer (score 0):

That was because I'm using reactnavigation, and find out I need to use it's lifeCycle instead of react componentWillUnmount.
In my case I put a listener for willBlur state and its working fine,

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html